# How can I search the array with some of the letter/s of arrays objects?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, search

How can I search the array with some of the letter/s of arrays objects?

Ex:

```
let array:Array = ["apple", "watermelon", "peach", "pear"]
search(array, "w","m","l")
//Prints
"watermelon"
```

Thanks

Comment: `NSPredicate`? `NSRegularExpression`? What have you tried?

Comment: I couldn't tried anything. I wrote that example to show what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let array:Array = ["apple", "watermelon", "peach", "pear"]

func search(array: [String], letters: Character...) -> [String] {

    func containsAllLetters(item: String) -> Bool {
        for char in letters {
            if !contains(item, char) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    return array.filter(containsAllLetters)
}

search(array, "w","m","l")
```

Comment: Hi, How do I assing a var to Characters... ? I wanted to get data from user.

Comment: In that case it is not appropriate using a _variadic_ parameter for `letters`. Just redefine the function something like: `func search(array: [String], letters: [Character]) -> [String]` than an array of characters can be declared like this: `var userDefinedLetters: [Character] = ["w","m","l"]`

Comment: `func search(array: [String], letters: String) -> [String]` should do the job either but, in my opinion, it could bring some confusion to the consumer of your function. i.e. you are asking for a `String`, but it's _meaning_ is _array of characters_

Comment: so while calling function how am I going to write letters section?

Comment: Ups maybe I didn't get your problem right. Probably you might post it as a question with more details.

Comment: 1 more question. I wrote a  function and it prints the whole element values to console and also I want to assign all values to resultLabel.text but it only writes one value in label :((       func getNew(){
        var letters = firstInput.text
        var res = search(array: dict, letters: letters)
        for element in res {
           resultLabel.text = element
            println("\(element)")
        }
        
        }

Answer (score 2):

In theory, this would be an ideal application of `find`, which returns the index of the first matching element of a collection (or `nil` if not found).

Except oops, for some strange reason there is no version of `find` that takes a predicate (unlike `contains`).  Easy to write one though:

```
func find<C: CollectionType>(source: C, match: C.Generator.Element->Bool) -> C.Index? {

    for idx in indices(source) {
        if match(source[idx]) {
            return idx
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Then it’s just a question of finding the right predicate.  In your case, you want to check that every element of a test set of characters is present.  Really you need an `all` function for that:

```
let array:Array = ["apple", "watermelon", "peach", "pear"]

let idx = find(array) {
    for char in "wml" {
        if !contains($0, char) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

if let foundIdx = idx {
    // prints “watermelon” 
    println(array[foundIdx])
}
else {
    println("No match")
}
```

You could also abstract that inner `for` loop into a function like `all` which returns true if every element of a collection matches:

```
func all<S: SequenceType>(source: S, match: S.Generator.Element->Bool) -> Bool {
    return !contains(source) { !match($0) }
}
```

which would allow you simplify to:

```
let idx = find(array) { str in
    all("wml") { char in
        contains(str, char)
    }
}
```

or, if you wanted an array of all the matching words rather than the index of the first match:

```
let matches = filter(array) { str in
    all("pl") { char in
        contains(str, char)
    }
}
// matches = [apple]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let array:Array = ["apple", "watermelon", "peach", "pear"]

func search<T>(source: [T], condition: (T) -> Bool) -> T? {

  var matches = lazy(source).filter(condition).generate()

  return matches.next()

}

extension String {
  func containsAllChars(chars: String) -> Bool {
    return !contains(chars) {letter in !contains(self, letter)}
  }
}

search(array) {$0.containsAllChars("wml")} // "watermelon"
```

Comment: Your use of `lazy` here is a bit pointless, since you then turn the result into an `array` before calling `first`.  So you may as well write `return filter(source, condition).first`.  Of course, this does what you may have been trying to avoid which is generating the entire array just to take the first element.  Annoyingly the free `first` function requires a collection.  `var g = lazy(source).filter(condition).generate();return g.next()` would do the trick.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it! Yeah, you're dead right. I was just trying to figure out a way to do it without the var, but `lazy(source).filter(condition).generate().next()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a fun way to do something like this you could use a string score on list items then return the top match! Basically you would have a list result of a list of objects containing the percentage match and the original item and just sort the list based on the match returning the best solution. Might be a more extensible way of implementing this or it could just be overkill... The other answers work just fine! :)

Here is a string score module written in swift you can use if you'd like to do this:

https://github.com/yichizhang/StringScore_Swift

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just a total different approach using Sets which take functions like union, intersect and in this case subtract.

The idea is to have two sets.
1. is the letters set containing all the letters that must be checked to be "in"
2. is the wordSet, that is the letters in each word (each fruit) of the array

If you can subtract all of the letterSet by going through the letters of the WordSet leaving an empty letterSet, the word meets the criteria.

Here is the code:

let array = ["apple", "watermelon", "peach", "pear"]

```
    func search(array: [String], letters: Character...) -> [String] {

        var resultArray = [String]()

        let letterSet = Set(letters)

        for word in array {
            let wordSet = Set(word)

            if letterSet.subtract(wordSet).isEmpty {
                resultArray.append((word))
            }
        }
        return resultArray
    }

    let resultArray = search(array, "w","m","l")
    println("Result: \(resultArray)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This one to search characters or strings as well

```
func search(array: [String], words: String...) -> [String] {
  let result = array.filter {
    for word in words {
      if !($0 as NSString).containsString(word) {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  }
  return result
}

let array = ["apple", "watermelon", "peach", "pear"]

println(search(array, "water", "on"))
println(search(array, "pe", "a"))
```